# How to prevent internet explorer from inserting a page break before multi page image

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm running IE11 on Windows 8.1 and I cant seem to get it to print the following without inserting a page break before the image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Text</p>
   <img src=".....\pic.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

Where pic.gif could be any image with a height greater than the size of the page it is trying to print to. If I print in in Chrome, it will show "Text" and then immediately below it start printing the image. But IE11 will insert a page break so the only thing on page 1 of the printed document is "Text" followed by a ton of white space. If I resize the image to be small enough to fit on 1 page it doesn't insert a page break, but resizing the image is not an option. Also - I am aware of the page-break-before: avoid; css but it makes no difference - it still inserts a page break.

Is it simply a bug in IE or is there any other way to force it? It seems to me like this is a problem that would have bitten many people in the past but I haven't had any luck finding others with this problem. I can reproduce it on many computers so I'm fairly sure its not just something out of whack in that regard.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into any of the [Paged Media Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772053(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `<p>` and `<img>` inside a `<div>` then add this to the div's css

```
page-break-after: avoid; 
page-break-before: avoid; 
page-break-inside: avoid;
```

Comment: This worked, but only if I put the div around JUST the img, not the <p> and the <img>. Not sure why that is but its good enough for my needs.